# Oracle pl/sql Change Array Size and Members After Delete

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

For example i have an array like 
`"a(1):=1 ,a(2):=2, a(3) := 3"` 
and now my array count =3 `"(a.count)"` 
then i delete middle member `"a.delete(2)"` then i wanna make my array like this `"a(1):=1;a(2):=3"` and my array count = 2 `("a.count")` how can i do this ?

ps:i need to this with big sized array so i think i should use, for or while loop but how...

Answer (score 0):

The collection where you have deleted some element is called sparse collection. Below you have example how to iterate that type of collection and how to use it with forall.

```
    declare
      type a is table of number;
      ar a;
      v_idx number;
    begin 
    select level bulk collect into ar from dual connect by level< 1000;
    ar.delete(1);
    ar.delete(4);
    ar.delete(10);
    ar.delete(88);
    v_idx := ar.first;
     while v_idx is not null loop
      dbms_output.put_line('idx: '||v_idx ||' value:'|| ar(v_idx));
      v_idx := ar.next(v_idx);
     end loop;      
     -- FORALL i IN INDICES OF ar
 --   INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ar(i);
    end;
```

Comment: Thank you but i should change array too , i need to take same output when i print array members like
for i in ar.first..ar.last loop
dbms_output.put_line(ar(i));
end loop;

Answer (score 0):

Thank you but i should change array too , i need to take same output when i print array members like

```
for i in ar.first..ar.last loop
dbms_output.put_line(ar(i));
end loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 declare
      type a is table of number;
      ar a;
    begin 
    select level bulk collect into ar from dual connect by level< 1000;
    ar.delete(1);
    ar.delete(4);
    ar.delete(10);
    ar.delete(88);
   -- ar is sparse collection;  
    ar := ar MULTISET intersect ar;
    -- ar is dense collection and for i in .... is possible 
    FOR i IN ar.first .. ar.last LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(ar(i));
    END LOOP;
 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this approach assign values of first spared collection to second continues collection and use second collection for further processing...

```
declare
  type num_arr is table of number;
  v_num_arr1  num_arr; --first collection
  v_num_arr2  num_arr := num_arr(); -- second collection initialization and declaration
  v_idx       number;
  v_col_index number := 1;
begin
  -- fill 10 element.
  select level || '1' as num1 bulk collect into v_num_arr1 from dual connect by level < 10;

  for x in v_num_arr1.first .. v_num_arr1.last loop
    dbms_output.put_line('index: ' || x || ' value: ' || v_num_arr1(x));
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('');
  -- delete element
  v_num_arr1.delete(3);
  v_num_arr1.delete(7);

  v_idx := v_num_arr1.first;

  while v_idx is not null loop
    dbms_output.put_line('index: ' || v_idx || ' value: ' || v_num_arr1(v_idx));
    -- filling second collection with regular index by variable v_col_index
    if v_num_arr1(v_idx) is not null then
      v_num_arr2.extend(1);
      v_num_arr2(v_col_index) := v_num_arr1(v_idx);
      v_col_index := v_col_index + 1;
    end if;
    v_idx := v_num_arr1.next(v_idx);
  end loop;

  dbms_output.put_line('second collection elements
  '); 
 --check second colleciton
  for x in v_num_arr2.first .. v_num_arr2.last loop
    dbms_output.put_line('index: ' || x || ' value: ' || v_num_arr2(x));
  end loop;
end;
```